# Passing Variables

Tags: actionscript-3

Can you please give me some leads into passing variables from a HTML(or)ASP.NET file to Flash Action Script 3 file.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Please, read this:
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) is an in-depth tutorial by Adobe on this subject.

To summarize, you have two options:

1. Add FlashVars="myVariable=value" attribute to your <embed> tag which embeds your SWF
2. Add <param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=value"/> to your <object> tag which embeds your SWF

After this you can access your "key" variable from the document class or any display object attached to the stage using:

```
var myVariable:String = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.myVariable.toString();
```

Good luck coding : j